# How to stop Background scrolling when modal box is in view in the mobile , just using CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a responsive website where when the user is in the mobile, he/she gets to view a modal box. To achieve that I am not using Bootstrap, just plain CSS and bit of Javascript. Now, the issue is that I cannot figure out how to stop the background ,or rather the main body to be specific, to scroll while the modal box is in view. I tried to manipulate the `overflow-y` from `scroll` to `hidden` using JS however, it does not work or may be thats not the right way, i just tried it. Anyhow, I checked out some answers in Stackoverflow, they are using bootstrap 3. I want a solution for this problem without using bootstrap 3, just using pure CSS or Javascript, I would really appreciate it if its possible. Thanks for your response.

PS: Just a note I am not avoiding bootstrap, I just want to know if there is a possible solution using simple CSS and JS.

Answer (score 2):

- For this you have to apply `css` on `body` tag **DYNAMICALLY**

**[JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/mmRnq/407/)**

Add the following code when dialogue is opened to stop the scroll on background

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

Add this when you close the popup - to enable scroll again

```
$("body").css("overflow", "auto");
```

- Try to add below reference in your `html` `<head>` tag.

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>`

**Working Demo[- Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/mmRnq/407/)**

Comment: @ZubairAnwar -  check-out the link for jsfiddle above.

Comment: I checked it out and it works like a charm on the desktop but not in Safari for iOS8, any thoughts ? Note: I dint use jquery for mobile just plain jquery.

Comment: I think you have to add mobile js on your page like -  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> `

Comment: this is the fiddle as to how I did it if you could check it out, it would be awesome,  http://jsfiddle.net/6o5jhcra/ , now this is a silly question if I add the jquery mobile here will still work in the mobile ?

Comment: I have seen your jsfiddle - it looks perfect and I have no clue related to mobile JQuery because it's new to me also :( but I think you have to add mobile js and than check in mobile devices